# Unity3d: Build test runner from command line (PlayMode tests generated via AQA)

Tags: unity-game-engine, automated-tests

I'm using the ["Automated QA" Package (AQA)](https://forum.unity.com/threads/automated-qa-package-v0-7.1089943/) to record some Unity PlayMode tests for my game.

What I cannot do:

- Generate a "UnityTestRunner" .apk from command line

Does anyone know how to do this?

I need this for my CI/CD pipeline, which automatically build such apks and test them on multiple local or cloud android devices.

Here some context:

Here is what's working:
I generate

- the recordings .json
- then generate "full tests"

I can open the "Test Runner" window inside the Unity Editor and

- Run selected Tests (PlayMode)

  - in Unity Editor and on
  - Android devices
- I can also launch the test from command line (powershell):

```powershell
$process = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Unity.exe" `
    -ArgumentList `
    "-logFile testLogFile.log`
    -projectPath ./MyGame/ `
    -testResults testResults/results.xml `
    -runTests `
    -testPlatform PlayMode "
```

- or on a connected Android phone by replacing `-testPlatform PlayMode` with `-testPlatform Android`

-> However, I don't want the tests to run on directly connected devices. Instead I want to build an apk and install them on any device (cloud or local). As I said, it works interactively: Open Unity Editor -> TestRunner -> BuildAllTests (Android) [see picture below]. But I don't know how to do it from command line.

[image]

**Update**
Apparantly parts of the Unity GUI are [scriptable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem.html). Not sure if / how this can be used to aumatomate the script runnter build ...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
$process = Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.26f1\Editor\Unity.exe" `
    -ArgumentList `
    "-logFile testLogFile.log`
    -projectPath ./MyGame/ `
    -testResults testResults/results.xml `
    -runTests `
    -testPlatform Android "
```

does create a "Temp" folder in the project root and therein a "PlayerWithTests.apk" hidden in some subpath.
[Here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1931743/view.html) is a more elaborate answer.